# CakePHP: Transport config "gmail" is missing

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.0.15 so I had to `use Cake\Network\Email\Email;` instead of `use Cake\Mailer\Email;`. Anyways, I have my `EmailTransport` in `app.php` configured like this:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'gmail' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'examplesender@gmail.com',
        'password' => 's2d5f8t9',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
    ]
],
```

And have this in my controller:

```
    $email = new Email();
    $email->transport('gmail')
        ->to('examplereveiver@gmail.com', 'Example Receiver')
        ->from('examplesender@gmail.com', 'Example Sender')
        ->subject('Test Subject')
        ->send('Message!!!!!');
```

Then it gives me the error:

```
Transport config "gmail" is missing.
```

However, when I configure the transport in my controller, just before using it, like this:

```
    Email::configTransport('gmail', [
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'examplesender@gmail.com',
        'password' => 's2d5f8t9',
        'className' => 'Smtp'
    ]);
```

It works and sends the email. Still, I'd like to configure the transport in `app.php` so I would be able to use the same transport config multiple times.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe your `config/bootstrap.php` is missing the `Email::configTransport()` call...

Comment: Hi @ndm, thanks! I checked my `config/bootstrap.php` and found out that `Email::configTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));` was commented out. So I uncommented it and found out that my `config/bootstrap.php` imports `Cake\Mailer\Email` instead of `Cake\Network\Email\Email`, so I replaced it and now everything is working. But now I'm just worried that I may have broken something else by replacing it. I'm just wondering why it used to import `Cake\Mailer\Email` when it was not used before CakePHP 3.1.

Comment: I have no idea, maybe you modified it, maybe you've used a newer CakePHP application template and downgraded the framework, ... who knows. Maybe you've explained something related to that at the beginning of your question, wich is missing.

Comment: @ndm Oops, didn't notice it was missing, sorry for that. Anyways, I'm working on an existing project so I'm not really sure. I think though that it's safe replacing it since `Email` is only used in `configTransport()` in `config/bootstrap.php` and now it's working. Anyways, thank you very much as you pretty much solved my problem.